# How to limit length of data in the output -sql

Tags: sql

```
SELECT po.po_number .... SOME QUERY
WHERE  po.po_number not like '%[^0-9]%' AND (mai.removed = 0)
ORDER BY mai.unique_issue_id
```

Here the output that I am getting is 10-digit numeric value , but I want 10-digit as well as 8 digit numeric, please suggest.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 1):

On SQL Server, just CAST or CONVERT your data to the output type you want:

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(NUMERIC(10,0), po.po_number) AS [Number10d],
    CONVERT(NUMERIC(8,0), po.po_number) AS [Number8d]
...
```

Comment: The query is written on .rdlc page , and I want to restrict the value (8 0r 10 there ). please suggest a way of doing it there

Comment: Well in that case, this is not really an SQL question, is it? :-)